# is this the right truth table?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

When I filled out the table I tried my best to figure it out. But If I made any mistakes please help me correct them. Thanks!

[image]

sorry 5th one should be false

Comment: You might want to consider assigning numbers to truth tables.  Or assigning an ordering to truth values like F<T, FF<TT, and FFF<TTT and so on (or T>F, TT>FF, TTT>FFF and so on).  Why?  Because if you do this, you can literally count, in some sense of the term count, to make sure that you've covered all possible cases.  How so?  Well say I assign 0 to F, and 1 to T.  Then since we can recognize that 000<001, 001<010, 010<011, 011<100, 100<101, 101<110, 110<111, then you have a method which helps you make sure that you've written all possible combinations of truth values.  Oh...

Comment: and there also exists a very advanced, or at least potentially interesting, and arguably important, logical topic which actually relies on such an *assignment* to truth values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: **UPDATE**

Now your table is mostly correct.

- Check your truth value assignment columns; we need to cover all possible $2^3$ truth-value assignments, and you've missed, for example, $P = F, Q = T, R = T$, but double counted another.)
- The only truth value combination that is **false** is when we have $P = F, Q = T, R = T$.  Then and only then is it the case that $P \lor \lnot Q \lnot R = F \lor F \lor F = F$.  For all other truth value combinations, the compound disjunction is true.
- The truth values listed in your columns below $P$ and $Q$ are
  slightly off. Compare the columns below with your columns.

[image]

Comment: Small nitpick: the fifth row is correct too.

Comment: Okay guys I have changed the picture please see it now.

Comment: @JavierBadia Is the new table okay?

Comment: You're welcome, MethodManX!

Comment: @amWhy: Pretty and color coded table! +1